# Android massive background data usage 38 GB month

Tags: data-monitoring, stock-email-app, background-data

I have Mediatek Smartphone with stock Android 7.0 and suddenly it increases data usage. Tracked it down to `/data/data/com.android.email/cache` which is occupying 1.6 GB. I have cleared cache many times which maybe explains the massive data usage 38 GB this month. The question is why it happens just now and not the months before?

How can i prevent increasing cache?

[image: 2019-04-29_16_37_15.png]

**Edit:** I use the stock email app for about 1 year without problems. I have 2x IMAP accounts connected. Recently I updated security patches to latest available Dec 2018 _V22. But after firmware update the battery drain increases too fast, so I decided to revert back to May 2018 CUBOT_KING_KONG_7081C_V16_20180517 (both still 7.0, no updates 7.1.2 available).

The phone is rooted so I can see that it downloades many files `body1009174325.tmp` in cache folder each with size 44,76 KB. I have inspected this file and it turns out it is a corrupt PDF which is downloaded a million times again and again. I found the responsible email and the App says attachment download has failed. After I pressed "save" the attachment was successful downloaded. After I cleared cache, the tmp files are gone. Now it starts repeating with next message (different tmp files, all the same). This time it is not a PDF and its hard to find the related email.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: I guess that is some Chinese smartphone with good load of bloat on it, so disable that app and use different one from store. Do you even use that app?

Comment: Do you use the E-Mail app? What is your device? How old are the installed security patches?  May be there is malware on your system that runs code inside the E-Mail app for e.g. advertisement video fraud.

Comment: It is Cubot phone with known stock spy malware com.adups.fota + com.adups.fota.sysoper. i have recently re-enabled (to update security patches) but its disabled now and before

Comment: If you need to access email from this phone, and are open for an alternative, head over to our sister site [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), describe your requirements, and install the outcoming email app (e.g. [k-9 mail](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.fsck.k9/)). Then disable the one that shipped with the device, and be done with. I'm using k-9 for almost 10 years now, never had such an issue with any of the 3 configured accounts.

Comment: fyi: solved by - clear data - from settings - email app

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @alecxs Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Netguard](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/eu.faircode.netguard/) can be an amazing choice in this situation. You can block apps from taking up unnecessary data, and can also allow apps of your choice to use data. I would most probably uninstall that email app since it's not secure. Give Netguard a try. (: